# Multi radio button with same name required architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, model-binding, forms, http-post

I have a form which has unknown amount of radio type inputs in it. So I have to use array for it in the model part.

That is my form

```
<form method="post" action="/File/Validate">
    <input type="number" name="fileId" value="@file.ID" class="hidden" />
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @foreach (var item in file.LABEL)
        {
            string id = item.KLASS.KLASS_NAME + i;
            <div id="@id">
                <input name="klassId[]" value="@item.KLASS.ID" class="hidden"/>
                <p>Class name : @item.KLASS.KLASS_NAME</p>
                <input type="radio" name="result" value="true" />Correct<br />
                <input type="radio" name="result" value="false" />Wrong/Unsure<br />
            </div>
            i++;
                    }
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button> 
</form>
```

That is the model

```
public class Validator
{
    public int fileId { get; set; }
    public int[] klassId { get; set; }
    public bool[] result { get; set; }
}
```

and that's the controller part

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Validate(Validator validator)
{}
```

my problem is that when I click on the radio buttons only one of the answer goes to backend however the amount of KLASSes is unknown everytime. So what should I do what kind of solution do you suggest? 
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're rendering all the radios with the same name  :

```
<div id="id-1">
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="true" />Correct<br /> 
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="false" />Wrong/Unsure<br />
    ...
</div>
<div id="id-2">
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="true" />Correct<br /> 
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="false" />Wrong/Unsure<br />
    ...
</div>
<div id="id-3">
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="true" />Correct<br /> 
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="result" value="false" />Wrong/Unsure<br />
    ...
</div>
```

See that ? Here you have 3 groups of radios, but all of the radios share the same name . In other words ,  **only one of the radios will be selected , and only one of them will be sent to server** .

Another thing I have to say is that I don't think it's a good idea to post the `result[]` and `klassId[]` as separate arrays. If somebody does not have the the second radio group checked , you'll get 3 `klassId` and 2 `result` on server side , thus has no idea about which the two radios are selected .

A better way is to create a new DTO to hold the `klassId-result` group , let's name it as `ValidatorDetail`:

```
public class ValidatorDetail
{
    public int klassId { get; set; }
    public bool result { get; set; }
}
```

To send the them as an array , you can render the fields with an index in your view page:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Validate">
    <input type="number" name="fileId" value="@file.ID" class="hidden" />
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @{ var i = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in file.LABEL)
    {
        string id = item.KLASS.KLASS_NAME + i;
        <div id="@id">
            <input name="details[@i].klassId" value="@item.KLASS.ID" class="hidden"/>
            <p>Class name : @item.KLASS.KLASS_NAME</p>
            <input type="radio" name="details[@i].result" value="true" />Correct<br />
            <input type="radio" name="details[@i].result" value="false" />Wrong/Unsure<br />
        </div>
        i++;
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button> 
</form>
```

Lastly , change your controller action as below :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Validate(int fileId,[FromForm]ValidatorDetail[] details)
{
    return new JsonResult(details);
}
```

It will work as expected .

Comment: it really worked for me thank you for your great answer it will help me improve my good practice mentality :) 
by the way where can i learn good practice is there any book for it or shold i keep writing and in search i can improve my practice

Comment: @Johnyy66554 I didn't know such a book . But MDN and `learn.microsoft.com` are my best friends .